# Sending cart data to server using Angular

Tags: post, e-commerce, ionic5, angular11

I am building an ecommerce site. I want to send the order data during checkout but I am unable to make the order data. Help needed

I am sending it statically below. It is working but how can I make it dynamic through iteration of this.mycart object

```
const body = new HttpParams()
.set('user_id', user_id)
.set('address_id', '89')
.set('final_price', this.grandtotal)
.set('payment_method', 'cod')
.set('txnid', '')
.set('payment_status', '0')
.set('slot_time', '12pm to 2pm')
.set('product_id[0]', this.mycart[0].id)
.set('product_name[0]', this.mycart[0].name)
.set('product_price[0]', this.mycart[0].price)
.set('quantity[0]', this.mycart[0].quantity)
.set('product_unit[0]', this.mycart[0].value)
.set('product_id[1]', this.mycart[1].id)
.set('product_name[1]', this.mycart[1].name)
.set('product_price[1]', this.mycart[1].price)
.set('quantity[1]', this.mycart[1].quantity)
.set('product_unit[1]', this.mycart[1].value);
      
 return this.httpClient.post(this.REST_API_SERVER+'user/place_order2', body.toString(), {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
 });
```

Comment: Please can you add more info. to show what your `this.mycart object` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working solution from one of my senior

/* Creating cart array */

const cartLoop = (httpBody, index, cartItems) => {

```
        httpBody['product_id['+index+']'] = cartItems.id;
        httpBody['product_name['+index+']'] = cartItems.name;
        httpBody['product_price['+index+']'] = cartItems.price;
        httpBody['quantity['+index+']'] = cartItems.quantity;
        httpBody['product_unit['+index+']'] = cartItems.value;
        
        return httpBody;
      }
      
      let cartData = {
        'user_id' : user_id,
        'address_id' : extraData.address_id,
        'final_price': this.grandtotal,
        'payment_method': extraData.payment_method,
        'txnid': extraData.payment_method,
        'payment_status': extraData.txnid,
        'slot_time': extraData.slot_time
      }

        for(var i=0; i<this.mycart.length; i++)
        {
          const cartItems = this.mycart[i];
          cartData = cartLoop(cartData, i, cartItems);
        }

        let body = new HttpParams({
          fromObject : cartData
        })

      return this.httpClient.post(this.REST_API_SERVER+'user/place_order2', body.toString(), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      })
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.